# How to add a package in the android studio - flutter?

Tags: flutter

I started fluttering a few days ago. I want to add "font awesome" to my project, but I can't. I searched but could not find the right answer. I finally got this guide, but it doesn't work either.

> Adding a package dependency to an app

To add the package, css_colors, to an app:

1. Depend on it

Open the pubspec.yaml file located inside the app folder, and add css_colors: under dependencies.

2. Install it

From the terminal: Run flutter pub get.
OR
From Android Studio/IntelliJ: Click Packages get in the action ribbon at the top of pubspec.yaml.

3. Import it

Add a corresponding import statement in the Dart code.
4. Stop and restart the app, if necessary

If the package brings platform-specific code (Kotlin/Java for Android, Swift/Objective-C for iOS), that code must be built into your app. Hot reload and hot restart only update the Dart code, so a full restart of the app might be required to avoid errors like MissingPluginException when using the package.

Answer (score 0):

In the dependencies: section of your pubspec.yaml, add the following line:

```
dependencies:
  font_awesome_flutter:
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter/install
It contain examples and instructions.

Steps also the same:

1. add the package name to dependencies section. It very important to keep the correct number of spaces in every line of pubspec.yaml, it has very sensitive format

in your case:

```
dependencies:
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.10.0
```

2. Click "Packeges get" in top right corner
3. Import the package into your dart code

in your case:

```
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
```

4. Now your can use it in Icon widget

   ```
   Icon(
    FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
    size:80.0)
   ```